# Multiplicar campo de entrada mysql y formulario php

Tags: php, mysql, formularios

Buenas me gustaria hacer un calculo, ente un campo de mi base de datos y un dato introducido por un formulario, no consigo que me salga... El dato de base de datos es interno guardado en una tabla y el otro uno que introduce el usuario por un formulario.

```
    <?php
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "prestashopprueba";

$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM ps_product";
$resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

echo "<table borde='2'>";
echo "<th>weight</th>";
echo "<th>num1</th>";
echo "<th>*</th>";

$num1=$_GET["num1"];
$multi=0;

// Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
{
$multi =  $num1 * $row['weight'];
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $num1 . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $multi . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
//echo $multi;
echo "</table>"; 


mysqli_close( $conexion );


?>
<head>

</head>
<form method="post" action="new1.php">
Introduce los m²: <input type="number" name="num1" />
<!--Introduce el rendimiento: <input id="num2" type="num2" name="num2" />
Introduce el rendimiento: <input id="num2" type="number" />-->
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="multiplicar" name="multi" /><br />
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Prueba a poner en el input type number `name="num1"` O prueba hacer un `echo` a `$row['weight']` para ver lo que te trae de la BD

Comment: pon como mandas tu formulario, y que error es el que te está marcando

Comment: Cual es el error que te arroja?

Comment: Hola, Lo que tu código esta haciendo es sumar el ultimo campo traído de la base de datos y asignarlo ha `$multi`, si lo que quieres es que ese resultado sea acumulativo debes usar `$multi+=`

Comment: Buenas ya añadi el name="num1" , la base de datos si trae el campo bien. Me salta el siguiente error                                                               ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: num1 in A:\wamp64\www\prestashopprueba\new1.php on line 18
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 247720 {main}( ) ...\new1.php:0                                     Añadi el$multi += pero me suma los campos de la columen                                           Mi idea es que multiplique un campo por lo que meta en el formulario

Comment: Aparte de lo que ha señalado @Kevin, ten en cuenta que para recibir tu valor por `GET` o por `POST` tu `input` tiene que tener una etiqueta `name` que es la que se usa para recuperar el valor. **`<input name="num1" type="number" />`**. GET y POST no reconocen el `id` sino el `name` por eso cuando haces esto: `$_GET["num1"];` te dice *undefined index...* porque entre los datos enviados no hay nada que se llame `num1`

Comment: si eso ya lo solucione, pero sigue sin funcionar... gracias por responder

Comment: Para que multiplique el número obtenido por el valor en la base de datos sería: `$num1 * $row['weight']` Ver **[Operadores ariméticos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.arithmetic.php)** en el Manual de PHP.

Comment: si bueno el hecho es que no lo hace  gracias

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no hace? ¿Has depurado las variables: `echo $num;` y  `echo $row['weight'];` arrojan bien los valores? ¿qué error estás teniendo? También fíjate que tu `table` no está escrita correctamente... cierras la etiqueta `table` y el echo de `$multi` no ocurre en ninguna fila ni celda concreta de la `table` quizá por eso no lo estés viendo.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas corregir el `input`:

```
<input name="num1" type="number" />
```

La etiqueta `name` es la utilizada para recuperar los valores por `GET` o `POST`.

Luego, tu tabla debe estar bien construida, de lo contrario no se mostrará.

Imaginaré que es una tabla con tres columnas. La puedes adaptar. Quité la cabecera Nombre porque no veo ningún dato relativo.

No estoy seguro, pero es posible que necesites indicar que quieres un array asociativo, para poder encontrar los valores por sus nombres de columna, por eso he indicado esto en el `fetch`: `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

...

```
echo "<table borde='2'>";
echo "<th>weight</th>";
echo "<th>num1</th>";
echo "<th>*</th>";

$num1=$_GET["num1"];
$multi=0;

// Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
{
    $multi =  $num1 * $row['weight'];
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $num . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $multi . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
//echo $multi;
echo "</table>"; 

mysqli_close( $conexion );
```

Comment: Buenas he modifciado el código, me salta el siguiente error.( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: num1 in A:\wamp64\www\prestashopprueba\new1.php on line 18
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 249080 {main}( ) ...\new1.php:0                                      Ahora con esto como puedo hacer el calculo? de la fila con el formulario? saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en tu formulario tienes el método de envío mediante `POST`, en cambio en el archivo `PHP` recoges el valor de tu `input type="number" name="num1"` como `$_GET["num1"]`. Deberías recoger los con `$_POST["num1"]`. Tambien si el dato que envias en el formulario al archivo PHP, puedes poner en el `action` esto: `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php

    $usuario = "root";
    $password = "";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "prestashopprueba";

    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM ps_product";
    $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

    echo "<table borde='2'>";
        echo "<th>weight</th>";
        echo "<th>num1</th>";
        echo "<th>*</th>";

        $num1=$_POST["num1"];
        $multi=0;

        // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
        {
            $multi =  $num1 * $row['weight'];
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $num1 . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $multi . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
       //echo $multi;
    echo "</table>"; 
    mysqli_close( $conexion );


?>
<head>

</head>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    Introduce los m²: <input type="number" name="num1" />
    <!--Introduce el rendimiento: <input id="num2" type="num2" name="num2" />
    Introduce el rendimiento: <input id="num2" type="number" />-->
    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="multiplicar" name="multi" /><br />
    </table>
</form>
```